# How to mock/access dojox using Jasmine and requireJS

Tags: dojo, requirejs, karma-jasmine

I'm using requireJS with karma and jasmine to test Dojo code.

As we know, require brings in all dependencies within each file, which is fine, however I get a script error when any of the files have language files (e.g. dojox/date/buddhist.js) as a dependency.

The language file is laid out as follows:

```
define([
  "..", 
  "dojo/_base/lang",
  "dojo/date", 
  "./buddhist/Date"
  ], function(
  dojox, 
  lang, 
  dd, 
  BDate
  ) { /* etc etc */
```

When referencing e.g. `"dojo/_base/lang"` this is easy to map to the file, however, notice the mapping to dojox is `".."` which actually goes back to a directory and not a single file.

This is the error I get in the terminal or console in browser:

> Error: Script error for "dojox", needed by: dojox/date/buddhist, dojox/date/buddhist/locale, dojox/date/hebrew, dojox/date/hebrew/locale, dojox/date/islamic, dojox/date/islamic/locale
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

I've tried defining dojox in my test-main file but same error.

So what I need to do is to mock dojox, is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by changing the dojox date files to reference an actual file:

Changed `".."` to `"dojox/main"` and mapped to that file.

I changed this within the actual dojo files as I use a copy of them in my test project, not sure if this would work in production but I think it would as it seems dojo have switched to this also in later versions.